# Java: Using MyLinkedList add method in iterator

Tags: java, eclipse, iterator, linked-list

This could be related to a problem with eclipse, but it is probably an issue with my code somewhere.  Anyway, I have a MyLinkedList class and I use an iterator with it.  When I was coding the iterator, it wasn't letting me use the add method by using MyLinkedList.list.add(x, index).  It tells me: "The method add(T, int) in the type MyLinkedList is not applicable for the arguments (T, int)".  The proposed fixes don't change anything of the code at all(like wanting to change the parameter types of the method from (T, int) to (T, int).  The remove method calls the same types of parameters and works fine.  I'll post the code to both the add method in MyLinkedList and the add method in the iterator.

The class:

```
public void add(T x, int index)
{
    if((index < 0) || (index > size))
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
    if(size == 0)
    {
        this.head = this.tail = new Node(x, null, null);
    }
    else if(index == 0)
    {
        this.head = new Node(x, this.head, null);
        this.head = this.head.getNext().getPrev();
    }
    else if(index == size)
    {
        this.tail = new Node(x, null, this.tail);
    }
    else 
    {
        Node<T> temp = new Node(null, null, null);

        temp.setData(x);
        if(index < this.size() / 2)
        {
            temp = this.head;
            for(int i = 0; i < index; i++)
            {
                temp = temp.getNext();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            temp = this.tail;
            for(int i = this.size(); i > index; i--)
            {
                temp = temp.getPrev();
            }
        }

        temp.getNext().setPrev(temp);
        temp.getPrev().setNext(temp);
        temp.setData(x);

    }
    this.size++;
}
```

The iterator method:

```
public void add(T x) 
    {
        if(modCount != expModCount)
            throw new ConcurrentModificationException();

        MyLinkedList.this.add(x, index); //the problem is in this line

        modCount--;
        index++;
    }
```

The entire program(there are definitely some things that aren't completely correct, but I'm more focused with the issue with the add method.  If you find any other problems with the code and would like to point me in the right direction, that would help me as well):

```
public class MyLinkedList<T> extends AbstractList<T> 
{

  private static class Node<T>
  {
    private T data;
    private Node<T> prev;
    private Node<T> next;

    /**
     * Constructor
     * @param nodeData - the data in type T that is stored in the node
     * @param nodePrev - the node previous to the node initialized
     * @param nodeNext - the node following the initialized node
     */
    public Node(T nodeData, Node<T> nodePrev, Node<T> nodeNext)
    {
        this.data = nodeData;
        this.prev = nodePrev;
        this.next = nodeNext;
    }

    /**
     * gets the node previous to this one
     * @return returns the node previous to this
     */
    public Node<T> getPrev()
    {
        return this.prev;
    }

    /**
     * sets the node previous to this
     * @param temp the node used to set the previous node to
     */
    public void setPrev(Node<T> temp)
    {
        this.prev = temp.prev;
    }

    /**
     * gets the node after this node
     * @return the node following this node
     */
    public Node<T> getNext()
    {
        return this.next;
    }

    /**
     * sets the node after this node in the list
     * @param prev - the node 
     */
    public void setNext(Node<T> prev)
    {
        this.next = prev.next;
    }

    /**
     * get the data from this node
     * @return the data from this node
     */
    public T getData()
    {
        return this.data;
    }

    /**
     * set the data in this node
     * @param data - the data to be put in this node
     */
    public void setData(T data)
    {
        this.data = data;
    }
}

private int size;
private int modCount;
public Node<T> head;
public Node<T> tail;

/**
 * Constructor for MyLinkedList that sets the head and tail of the list to point to null and the size set to 0
 */
MyLinkedList()
{
    this.head = new Node<T>(null, null, null);
    this.tail = new Node<T>(null, null, null);
    this.size = 0;
}


/**
 * gets the data from the node specified by the index
 * @param index - the index of the node
 * @return the data of the node with index index
 */
@Override
public T get(int index)
{
    Node<T> temp = new Node(null, null, null);

    if((index < 0) || (index > size))
    {
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
    }

    if(index < this.size() / 2)
    {
        temp = this.head;
        for(int i = 0; i < index; i++)
        {
            temp = temp.getNext();
        }

        return temp.getData();
    }
    else
    {
        temp = this.tail;
        for(int i = this.size(); i > index; i--)
        {
            temp = temp.getPrev();
        }

        return temp.getData();
    }
}

/**
 * adds data to the list at the specified index
 * @param x - the data to be stored
 * @param index - where in the list the data is stored
 */
public void add(T x, int index)
{
    if((index < 0) || (index > size))
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
    if(size == 0)
    {
        this.head = this.tail = new Node(x, null, null);
    }
    else if(index == 0)
    {
        this.head = new Node(x, this.head, null);
        this.head = this.head.getNext().getPrev();
    }
    else if(index == size)
    {
        this.tail = new Node(x, null, this.tail);
    }
    else 
    {
        Node<T> temp = new Node(null, null, null);

        temp.setData(x);
        if(index < this.size() / 2)
        {
            temp = this.head;
            for(int i = 0; i < index; i++)
            {
                temp = temp.getNext();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            temp = this.tail;
            for(int i = this.size(); i > index; i--)
            {
                temp = temp.getPrev();
            }
        }

        temp.getNext().setPrev(temp);
        temp.getPrev().setNext(temp);
        temp.setData(x);

    }
    this.size++;
}

/**
 * gets the size of the list
 * @return the size of the list
 */
@Override
public int size() 
{
    return this.size;
}

/**
 * @return returns whether or not the list is empty
 */
public boolean isEmpty()
{
    return (this.size() == 0);
}

/**
 * clears the list by setting the head and tail of the list equal to null and the size equal to 0
 */
public void clear()
{
    this.head = new Node<T>(null,null,null);
    this.tail = new Node<T>(null,null,null);

    this.tail = this.head.getNext();
    this.size = 0;
}

/**
 * removes a node from the list
 * @return the data from the removed node
 */
public T remove(int index)
{
    Node<T> temp;
    if ((index < 0) || (index >= size) || isEmpty())
    {
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
    }
    if(index == 0)
    {
        temp = new Node(this.head.getData(), null, this.head.getNext());
        this.head = this.head.getNext();
    }
    else
    {
        Node<T> prev = new Node(null,null,null);
        prev = getNth(index - 1);
        temp = new Node(prev.getNext().getData(), null, null);
    }
    this.size--;
    return temp.getData();
}

/**
 * gets the node at the index index
 * @param index - the index of the node we want to return
 * @return the node at the specified index
 */
private Node<T> getNth(int index)
{
    Node<T> temp;
    if(index < 0 || index > size)
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();

    if(index < this.size() / 2)
    {
        temp = this.head;
        for(int i = 0; i < index; i++)
        {
            temp = temp.getNext();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        temp = this.tail;
        for(int i = this.size(); i > index; i--)
        {
            temp = temp.getPrev();
        }
    }
    return temp;
}

private class Iterator<T> implements ListIterator<T>
{
    private Node<T> currentNode;
    private int expModCount = modCount;
    int index = 0;

    /**
     * adds the data to the list using the add method from MyLinkedList
     */
    @Override
    public void add(T x) 
    {
        if(modCount != expModCount)
            throw new ConcurrentModificationException();

        MyLinkedList.this.add(x, index);

        modCount--;
        index++;
    }

    /**
     * @return returns true if the current node is not the tail, returns false if the current node is the tail of the list
     */
    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() 
    {
        if (currentNode.equals(MyLinkedList.this.tail))
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }

    /**
     * @return returns true if the current node is not the head of the list, returns false if the current node is the head of the list
     */
    @Override
    public boolean hasPrevious()
    {
        if (currentNode.equals(MyLinkedList.this.head))
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }

    /**
     * @return the data from the next node
     */
    @Override
    public T next() 
    {
        if(modCount != expModCount)
            throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
        if(hasNext() == false)
            throw new NoSuchElementException();

        T nextData = currentNode.getData();
        currentNode.setData(currentNode.getNext().getData());

        index++;

        return nextData;
    }

    /**
     * @return the index of the next node
     */
    @Override
    public int nextIndex()
    {
        return index + 1;
    }

    /**
     * @return the data from the previous node
     */
    @Override
    public T previous() 
    {
        if(modCount != expModCount)
        {
            throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
        }
        if(hasPrevious() == false)
        {
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        }

        T prevData = currentNode.getPrev().getData();
        currentNode.setData(currentNode.getPrev().getData());

        index--;

        return prevData;
    }

    /**
     * @return the index of the previous node
     */
    @Override
    public int previousIndex() 
    {
        return index - 1;
    }

    /**
     * removes a node using the MyLinkedList remove method
     */
    @Override
    public void remove()
    {
        if(modCount != expModCount)
            throw new ConcurrentModificationException();

        MyLinkedList.this.remove(currentNode);
        modCount--;
    }

    /**
     * sets the data of the current node
     * @param x - the data to set to the current node.
     */
    @Override
    public void set(T x) 
    {
        currentNode.setData(x);
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Could you  please post the complete iterator code if possible even MyLinkedList code ?

Comment: updated to include everything

Comment: That can't be the whole code, can it? How are you creating iterator objects? It can't be outside of `MyList`, as you've declared `Iterator` private.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey the problem is type E in your Iterator interface and type E MyLinkedList class are colliding. If you remove the type E of Iterator this issue won't come. However to ensure the type safety , consider implementing it like it is implemented collection frameworks  for example something like in [AbstractList.java](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/AbstractList.java.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest way to solve this is to make your iterator not be a parameterized class, but rather, use the parameters from the outer class:

```
private class MyIterator implements ListIterator<T>
```

The way you have it set up, the `<T>` in `Iterator<T>` is masking the one in `MyLinkedList<T>`, and so, the compiler has no way to know whether they are the same type. Inner classes inherit the parameters from outer classes anyway, so you still have an available `T` in your iterator inner class.

The same reasoning applies to your `Node` class, by the way. You should remove the parameter from the class declaration. You can still use it in the class body, as it's inherited from the outer class.